# How to move GEvent.callbackArgs over to V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code which works under V2 and I am trying to move it over to V3.

The issue seems to be the access to the "this" object which holder the polyline to which the event is being added. (there are many such instantiations on the map so I don't necessary know which one is making the call when I receive the event, I can object the necessary information by passing this through the callbackArgs interface provided in V2)

I have read up on closures but I can't seem to see how I might apply them

```
            GEvent.addListener(this.intLineObj , "click",
            GEvent.callbackArgs(this, this.loadComments, null));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to find an answer to this one. I had to rewrite my code to access everything via an indexed global array. (not really what I wanted to do)